# nvm alias command not working on Windows 10

Tags: nvm

As the title says, I'm on Windows 10 and I'm using the latest 1.1.9 nvm version.

I keep two node versions, one for work and one for my personal use.

I want to set aliases for them but the command doesn't work.

When I type

```
nvm alias work 10.16.0 (I have the version installed)
```

I get listed the running version of nvm and the usage guide.

Then when I try

```
nvm use work
```

it says that "work" isn't a recognised version.

Comment: `nvm` (node version manager) works on Windows too? o.O

Comment: Yeah, I've been using it for quite a while and haven't really encountered any problems with it until now. I'm able to install and switch node versions without a problem, only this alias command is not working from what I can gather up to now :D

Comment: Maybe the Windows version is just bugged?

Comment: This is the reply from the nvm-windows author. Not yet supported. https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/503

Answer (score 4):

According to the GitHub Repository Issues, this version of nvm doesn't have a feature for Aliases.